# Linux permissions and owner being preserved with cp

Tags: linux, bash, unix, permissions, cp

I can't understand the following behavior:
I have a file named `someFile` under `/opt/com/internal/someFile`
If I do `ls -all /opt/com/internal/someFile` the permissions are `700 user:userGroup`

I am root and I do `cp /root/folder/someFile /opt/com/internal/someFile`

1. I don't get a prompt to overwrite. Why not?
2. The permissions are unchanged. But if I do `cp /root/folder/someFile /opt/com/internal/someFile` and the file `someFile` does not exist it is owned by `root` and not `user`. Why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I don't get a prompt to overwrite. Why not?

Because you're supposed to know what you're doing. Especially as root, you can overwrite pretty much anything, so pay attention to that.

Use the `-i` option for `cp` to get a prompt before overwriting existing files. If you always want to be reminded of this, consider [creating an alias](http://ss64.com/bash/alias.html) for `cp` to `cp -i`.

> The permissions are unchanged. But if […] file `someFile` does not exist it is owned by `root` and not `user`. Why?

Because the file you're copying to is already existing. It's not deleted and re-written. It's still owned by `user`.

However, check `cp`'s `-p` option. It will preserve the attributes of the source file, namely the mode, ownership and timestamps. Otherwise, the mode and ownership attributes of the target file will stay (except for the timestamps which will indicate a modification).

If there's no target file, obviously the attributes of the source file *need* to be copied, since they can't be inherited from a target file. You'll basically just create a new file, and in this case it's owned by `root`.

Comment: Just a comment on using aliases adding `-i`to `cp`/`rm`: it can be a problem if one gets used to this, and suddenly finds oneself on a system where these non-standard aliases are not set. It is good to not make a habit out of expecting them. "Default is almost always better", as I apparently said just now :-) .

Comment: Absolutely. If you're root you should be aware of that and it's not the first time I've seen someone overwrite important system files being too eager while copying.

Answer (score 2):

1) `cp` will not prompt for overwrite unless the `-i` argument is used, this has been the default behavior since the first unix

2)[from wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cp_%28Unix%29) : The overwriting of a file to an existing file is performed by opening the existing file in update mode, thereby preserving the files inode, which requires write access and results in the target file retaining the permissions it had originally.